# Linux - How to read data (containing multi line values) from a csv file and store to an array

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a test.csv file with the below content:

```
test 123
abc 456
def 789
hello hkdsfhhif
      kjsdfkjdshfkj
      jhkjsdfhksdfhksdh
hey 218es@#$9#RDS
```

I wrote a shell script:

```
while IFS=' ' read -ra array; do
  column+=("${array[0]}")
  column2+=("${array[1]}")

done < test.csv
printf '%s\n' "${column[@]}" "${column2[@]}"
```

The whole reason behind this is - column[1] is the key and column2[1] is its respective value.
Everything works as expected, except for the row - hello and its multi line value -hkdsfhhi..

Now my question is, how to read the data from csv if the data contains a multi line value.

Comment: If this were supposed to be a multi-value CSV file, it's syntactically wrong. If a cell contains linefeeds, the whole content must be enclosed in single quotes. As a CSV file, we have only one column in your example, and every physical line contains one field. You have now two choices: Either fix the program which produces the CSV, so that you get syntactically correct CSV, or post a definitio of the syntax used in your specific text file (but I suggest than to not call it "csv", as this could be confusing).

Comment: BTW, you find [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180) the definition of a CSV file. The multiline fields are covered in chapter 2, point 6. There is also an example similar to your case.

Comment: test.csv is just an example here. The main question here is - How to read data from a csv file in shell where value of a particular cell has multi line data. The multi line data needs to saved as a single value.

Comment: *`how to read data from a csv file`* depends on the format of the file; as already mentioned this is not a csv-formatted file so there's some confusion as to how your file is actually formatted; a csv-specific solution won't work here since the sample input is not csv formatted; if this sample is really what your file looks like then I'd recommend you edit the question to remove all references to 'csv'

Comment: can the 1st column/field contain a multi-line value? for a 2nd column/field that contains a multi-line value, can there be any embedded spaces in the value? if any values can contain white space then please update the question to show a sample; also, please update the question to show a) the (wrong) output generated by your code and b) the (correct) expected output

Comment: @Dheeraj : Then at least provide a **valid** example. I don't see a point in asking something using an unrealistic, syntacticallly incorrect input. For the general problem, parsing syntactically correct CSV is quite some task. Many programming language come with a CSV parser, and why would you re-invent the wheel? Even if I would want to implement the n-th CSV library, I would for sure not do it in _bash_.

Answer (score 0):

First, your input data has nothing to do with CSV. It’s an arbitrary custom format, which is OK, but calling it CSV sounds confusing.

Second, having keys in one array and values in another one is mostly frowned upon, because it opens a can of worms (possibly inconsistent states), such as a different size of the two arrays or other index mismatches.

Sadly, Bash doesn’t quite have a record / structure data type. So for this purpose, the closest approximation may be an associative array, under the following assumptions:

0. Lines have either two tokens (a key and a value) or a single token (a continuation of the previous value).
1. Whitespace doesn’t matter and doesn’t occur inside tokens (i.e. there is no quoting or escaping syntax).
2. Keys are unique or it is OK for the last occurrence of a key to “win” and overwrite the previous value.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

parse_data() {
  local -n target_array="$1"
  local first second old_key
  target_array=()
  while read -r first second; do
    if [[ -n "$second" ]]; then
      old_key="$first"
      target_array["$first"]="$second"
    else
      target_array["$old_key"]+="$first"
    fi
  done
}

declare -A data  # associative array
parse_data data << DATA
test 123
abc 456
def 789
hello hkdsfhhif
      kjsdfkjdshfkj
      jhkjsdfhksdfhksdh
hey 218es@#$9#RDS
DATA

for key in "${!data[@]}"; do
  printf '"%s" : "%s"\n' "$key" "${data["$key"]}"
done
```

Obviously, this↑ has no error checking whatsoever. So if the file (e.g.) starts with a multi-line value without a key, it causes an (associative) array subscript error etc. Not to mention empty lines, more than 2 tokens per line etc. *Possible* output from the snippet above:

```
"def" : "789"
"hello" : "hkdsfhhifkjsdfkjdshfkjjhkjsdfhksdfhksdh"
"hey" : "218es@##RDS"
"abc" : "456"
"test" : "123"
```

Note on the *“possible”* output: Associative arrays are hash maps with an undefined order of keys during iteration. If you need to keep a predictable key ordering, you can e.g. use an additional indexed array containing the keys. Iteration over the (integer-indexed) array of (string) keys pointing into the associative array (hash map) yields a predictable key ordering.